# Format for setEndDate and setStartDate?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datepicker

Using [bootstrap datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker).

[Documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#setenddate) doesn't mention which format is expected for `setEndDate` or `setStartDate`.
It refeers to endDate option, which doesn't either details the required format.

I do not want to base endDate and newDate on the current date, but on a specific date. For example:

```
Fri Aug 19 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It expects a JavaScript `Date` object. There are several ways to [create a Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Use `new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 7, 19, 0, 0, 0));` to create a Date on Fri Aug 19 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time) (month is zero based).